# Удаление значений из связанных таблиц

Tags: sql, sql-server

Значит, есть задача: существует несколько (неизвестное количество) таблиц, они связаны между собой средствами `FOREIGN` - `PRIMARY KEY`. Нужно удалить все записи с таблиц. К таблицам подключаться я не могу. Могу только подключиться к 1 (любой) и из неё вести уже удаление всех зависящих таблиц. Код:

```
    USE DB;
CREATE PROC DB_CLEAR
    @TABLE_NAME NVARCHAR(400) 
        AS
    BEGIN TRY
        EXEC('DELETE FROM ' + @TABLE_NAME)
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        DECLARE
            @ERR_FULL_MESSAGE NVARCHAR(400),
            @TEMP_STRING NVARCHAR(100),
            @START_TABLE_INDEX SMALLINT,
            @END_TABLE_INDEX SMALLINT,--
            @DEPENDED_TABLE NVARCHAR(100),
            ----------------------------------
            @DEPENDED_COLUMN NVARCHAR(100),
            @DEPENDED_COLUMN_TEMP NVARCHAR(100),
            @OWN_ID_START_INDX SMALLINT,
            @OWN_ID_END_INDX SMALLINT
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        SELECT
            @ERR_FULL_MESSAGE = ERROR_MESSAGE(),
            @START_TABLE_INDEX = CHARINDEX('table',ERROR_MESSAGE())
        SET @START_TABLE_INDEX = @START_TABLE_INDEX + 7

        SELECT @TEMP_STRING = SUBSTRING(ERROR_MESSAGE(),@START_TABLE_INDEX,LEN(ERROR_MESSAGE()))

        SET @END_TABLE_INDEX = CHARINDEX('column',@TEMP_STRING)
        SET @END_TABLE_INDEX = @END_TABLE_INDEX - 3;
        SET @DEPENDED_TABLE = SUBSTRING(@TEMP_STRING,0,@END_TABLE_INDEX) 
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------      
        SELECT 
            @OWN_ID_START_INDX = CHARINDEX('column', ERROR_MESSAGE())
        SET @OWN_ID_START_INDX = @OWN_ID_START_INDX + 8

        SELECT @DEPENDED_COLUMN_TEMP = SUBSTRING(ERROR_MESSAGE(),@OWN_ID_START_INDX,LEN(ERROR_MESSAGE()))

        SET @OWN_ID_END_INDX = CHARINDEX('.',@DEPENDED_COLUMN_TEMP)
        SET @OWN_ID_END_INDX = @OWN_ID_END_INDX - 1;
        SET @DEPENDED_COLUMN = SUBSTRING(@DEPENDED_COLUMN_TEMP,0,@OWN_ID_END_INDX)
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------     
        BEGIN TRY
        EXEC ('UPDATE ' + @DEPENDED_TABLE + 
             ' SET ' + @DEPENDED_COLUMN + ' = NULL ' + 
             ' WHERE Name != ''FIELD_NAME'' ') --THE FIELD NEEDED TO BE!
        EXEC ('UPDATE ' + @TABLE_NAME + 
             ' SET ' + @DEPENDED_COLUMN + ' = NULL' + 
             'WHERE ID != ''668241BB-86E3-49B6-98BA-E746F06730F9''') --THE FIELD NEEDED TO BE!

        END TRY 
        BEGIN CATCH
            PRINT ERROR_MESSAGE()
            COLUMN_REMOVER @DEPENDED_TABLE, @DEPENDED_COLUMN

        END CATCH
    END CATCH
    GO
EXEC DB_CLEAR 'dbo.TABLE_NAME' -- ТАБЛИЦА КОТОРУЮ НУЖНО УДАЛИТЬ(ПАРАМЕТР)
GO
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
CREATE PROC COLUMN_REMOVER
    @TABLE NVARCHAR(100)
    @COLUMN NVARCHAR(100)
    AS
    BEGIN TRY
        EXEC ('UPDATE ' + @TABLE + 
              ' SET ' + @COLUMN + ' = NULL')
    END TRY

    BEGIN CATCH
        PRINT ERROR_MESSAGE()
    END CATCH   
    GO
```

Comment: на русском, плиз

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что он не задан на русском языке

Comment: Воспользуйтесь этой инструкцией, чтобы добавить в вопрос всю информацию, необходимую для решения: http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/169/181472

Answer (score 2):

Так как таблицы и связи между ними заранее не известны то, чтобы удалить все связанные данные придется создавать динамические запросы. Для этого можно воспользоваться описанием связей `foreign key` - `primary key` получив его из [information_schema](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms186778%28v=SQL.120%29.aspx).

[SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com) что-то ругается на пример в отличии от [SSMS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt238486.aspx) так что выкладываю пример здесь.

Для начала создадим несколько таблиц и наполним их данными:

```
create table TableOne
(
  id int primary key
);

create table TableTwo
(
  id int primary key,
  tableOne_id int foreign key references TableOne(id)
);

create table TableThree
(
  id int primary key,
  tableTwo_id int foreign key references TableTwo(id)
);

create table TableFour
(
  id int,
  tableThree_id int foreign key references TableThree(id)
);

create table TableFive
(
  id int,
  tableOne_id int foreign key references TableOne(id)
)

insert into TableOne (id) values(1);
insert into TableOne (id) values(2);
insert into TableTwo (id, tableOne_id) values(1, 1);
insert into TableTwo (id, tableOne_id) values(2, 1);
insert into TableThree (id, tableTwo_id) values(3, 1);
insert into TableThree (id, tableTwo_id) values(4, 1);
insert into TableFour (id, tableThree_id) values(5, 3);
insert into TableFour (id, tableThree_id) values(6, 3);
insert into TableFive (id, tableOne_id) values(1, 2);
insert into TableFive (id, tableOne_id) values(2, 2);
```

Теперь создадим процедуру, которая внутри себя будет использовать рекурсивный запрос к метаданным для получения динамического запроса на удаления связанных строк:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE clear_table @table_name VARCHAR(max)
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @DROP_QUERY varchar(max);
    DECLARE QUERY_CURSOR CURSOR 
      LOCAL STATIC READ_ONLY FORWARD_ONLY
    FOR 
    with fk (query, deleteQuery, master_table, detail_table, master_column_name, detail_column_name, ord)
    as 
    (
      select 
        cast('select * from ' + ctu.TABLE_NAME + ' where ' + dccu.COLUMN_NAME + ' in (select ' + mccu.COLUMN_NAME + ' from ' + mccu.TABLE_NAME + ')'as varchar(max)) as query, 
        cast('delete from ' + ctu.TABLE_NAME + ' where ' + dccu.COLUMN_NAME + ' in (select ' + mccu.COLUMN_NAME + ' from ' + mccu.TABLE_NAME + ')' as varchar(max)) deleteQuery,
        mccu.TABLE_NAME master_table, 
        ctu.TABLE_NAME detail_table, 
        mccu.COLUMN_NAME master_column_name, 
        dccu.COLUMN_NAME detail_column_name,
        1 ord
      from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE mccu    
        join INFORMATION_SCHEMA.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS rc on rc.UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_NAME = mccu.CONSTRAINT_NAME
        join INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE dccu on dccu.CONSTRAINT_NAME = rc.CONSTRAINT_NAME
        join INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_TABLE_USAGE ctu on ctu.constraint_name = rc.CONSTRAINT_NAME
      where mccu.table_name = @table_name
      union all
      select 
        cast('select * from ' + ctu.TABLE_NAME + ' where ' + dccu.COLUMN_NAME + ' in (select ' + mccu.COLUMN_NAME + ' from (' + fk.query + ') s )'as varchar(max)) as query, 
        cast('delete from ' + ctu.TABLE_NAME + ' where ' + dccu.COLUMN_NAME + ' in (select ' + mccu.COLUMN_NAME + ' from (' + fk.query + ') s )' as varchar(max)) deleteQuery,
        mccu.TABLE_NAME master_table, 
        ctu.table_name detail_table, 
        mccu.COLUMN_NAME master_column_name, 
        dccu.COLUMN_NAME detail_column_name,
        fk.ord + 1
      from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE mccu    
        join INFORMATION_SCHEMA.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS rc on rc.UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_NAME = mccu.CONSTRAINT_NAME
        join INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE dccu on dccu.CONSTRAINT_NAME = rc.CONSTRAINT_NAME
        join INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_TABLE_USAGE ctu on ctu.constraint_name = rc.CONSTRAINT_NAME
        join fk on fk.detail_table = mccu.table_name
    )
    select deleteQuery
    from
    ( 
      select deleteQuery, ord 
      from fk
      union all
      select 'delete from ' + @table_name deleteQuery, 0 ord  
    ) s
    order by ord desc

    OPEN QUERY_CURSOR
    FETCH NEXT FROM QUERY_CURSOR INTO @DROP_QUERY
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN 
        EXEC(@DROP_QUERY)
        FETCH NEXT FROM QUERY_CURSOR INTO @DROP_QUERY
    END
    CLOSE QUERY_CURSOR
    DEALLOCATE QUERY_CURSOR
END;
```

Теперь попробуем с помощью нее удалить все данные из таблицы `TableOne`. Как видно из кода выше на таблицу `TableOne` ссылаются таблицы `TableTwo` и `TableFive`, а на таблицу `TableTwo` ссылается таблица `TableThree` и т.п. Но, благодаря использованию процедуры все связанные данные будут удалены:

```
exec clear_table 'TableOne'
```

Чтобы посмотреть какие запросы на удаление генерируются в процедуре можно отдельно выполнить рекурсивный запрос и посмотреть на результат его работы. В нашем случае для таблицы `TableOne` будут сгенерированны и последовательно выполнены следующие запросы:

```
delete from TableFour where tableThree_id in (select id from (select * from TableThree where tableTwo_id in (select id from (select * from TableTwo where tableOne_id in (select id from TableOne)) s )) s )
delete from TableThree where tableTwo_id in (select id from (select * from TableTwo where tableOne_id in (select id from TableOne)) s )
delete from TableTwo where tableOne_id in (select id from TableOne)
delete from TableFive where tableOne_id in (select id from TableOne)
delete from TableOne
```

**UPDATE**

Чтобы удалить данные только из той таблицы, имя которой нам передано в параметрах, нужно сначала удалить все `foreign key` которые смотрят на ее `primary key`, а затем уже стереть из нее данные.
Для этого можно воспользоваться той же метаинформацией и сгенерировать запросы на удаление `foreign key` после чего уже удалить данные из самой таблицы:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE clear_table2 @table_name VARCHAR(max)
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @DROP_QUERY varchar(max);
    DECLARE QUERY_CURSOR CURSOR 
      LOCAL STATIC READ_ONLY FORWARD_ONLY
    FOR 
    select 'alter table ' + ctu.table_name + ' drop constraint ' + rc.CONSTRAINT_NAME query      
    from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE mccu    
      join INFORMATION_SCHEMA.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS rc on rc.UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_NAME = mccu.CONSTRAINT_NAME
      join INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_TABLE_USAGE ctu on ctu.constraint_name = rc.CONSTRAINT_NAME
    where mccu.table_name = @table_name
    union all
    select 'delete from ' + @table_name query

    OPEN QUERY_CURSOR
    FETCH NEXT FROM QUERY_CURSOR INTO @DROP_QUERY
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN 
        EXEC(@DROP_QUERY)
        FETCH NEXT FROM QUERY_CURSOR INTO @DROP_QUERY
    END
    CLOSE QUERY_CURSOR
    DEALLOCATE QUERY_CURSOR
END;
```

Если вызвать ее с параметром `TableOne` то она сгенерирует и выполнит следующие запросы (имя констрейнтов может отличаться):

```
alter table TableFive drop constraint FK__TableFive__table__004002F9
alter table TableTwo drop constraint FK__TableTwo__tableO__7993056A
delete from TableOne
```

**UPDATE 2**

Чтобы уже сильно не менять процедуру доработаем ее так, как есть, добавив возможность указывать фильтр влияющий на удаляемые данные. Для этого добавим к процедуре еще один параметр и немного модифицируем способ генерации запросов:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE clear_table3 @table_name VARCHAR(max), @predicate varchar(max)
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @DROP_QUERY varchar(max);
    DECLARE QUERY_CURSOR CURSOR 
      LOCAL STATIC READ_ONLY FORWARD_ONLY
    FOR 
    with fk (query, deleteQuery, master_table, detail_table, master_column_name, detail_column_name, ord)
    as 
    (
      select 
        cast('select * from ' + ctu.TABLE_NAME + ' where ' + dccu.COLUMN_NAME + ' in (select ' + mccu.COLUMN_NAME + ' from ' + mccu.TABLE_NAME + ' ' + @predicate + ')'as varchar(max)) as query, 
        cast('delete from ' + ctu.TABLE_NAME + ' where ' + dccu.COLUMN_NAME + ' in (select ' + mccu.COLUMN_NAME + ' from ' + mccu.TABLE_NAME + ' ' + @predicate + ')' as varchar(max)) deleteQuery,
        mccu.TABLE_NAME master_table, 
        ctu.TABLE_NAME detail_table, 
        mccu.COLUMN_NAME master_column_name, 
        dccu.COLUMN_NAME detail_column_name,
        1 ord
      from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE mccu    
        join INFORMATION_SCHEMA.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS rc on rc.UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_NAME = mccu.CONSTRAINT_NAME
        join INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE dccu on dccu.CONSTRAINT_NAME = rc.CONSTRAINT_NAME
        join INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_TABLE_USAGE ctu on ctu.constraint_name = rc.CONSTRAINT_NAME
      where mccu.table_name = @table_name
      union all
      select 
        cast('select * from ' + ctu.TABLE_NAME + ' where ' + dccu.COLUMN_NAME + ' in (select ' + mccu.COLUMN_NAME + ' from (' + fk.query + ') s )'as varchar(max)) as query, 
        cast('delete from ' + ctu.TABLE_NAME + ' where ' + dccu.COLUMN_NAME + ' in (select ' + mccu.COLUMN_NAME + ' from (' + fk.query + ') s )' as varchar(max)) deleteQuery,
        mccu.TABLE_NAME master_table, 
        ctu.table_name detail_table, 
        mccu.COLUMN_NAME master_column_name, 
        dccu.COLUMN_NAME detail_column_name,
        fk.ord + 1
      from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE mccu    
        join INFORMATION_SCHEMA.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS rc on rc.UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_NAME = mccu.CONSTRAINT_NAME
        join INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE dccu on dccu.CONSTRAINT_NAME = rc.CONSTRAINT_NAME
        join INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_TABLE_USAGE ctu on ctu.constraint_name = rc.CONSTRAINT_NAME
        join fk on fk.detail_table = mccu.table_name
    )
    select deleteQuery
    from
    ( 
      select deleteQuery, ord 
      from fk
      union all
      select 'delete from ' + @table_name + ' ' + @predicate deleteQuery, 0 ord  
    ) s
    order by ord desc

    OPEN QUERY_CURSOR
    FETCH NEXT FROM QUERY_CURSOR INTO @DROP_QUERY
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN 
        EXEC(@DROP_QUERY)
        FETCH NEXT FROM QUERY_CURSOR INTO @DROP_QUERY
    END
    CLOSE QUERY_CURSOR
    DEALLOCATE QUERY_CURSOR
END;
```

Если вызвать эту процедур, например, так:

```
exec clear_table3 'TableOne', 'where id != 1'
```

То сформируются такие запросы:

```
delete from TableFour where tableThree_id in (select id from (select * from TableThree where tableTwo_id in (select id from (select * from TableTwo where tableOne_id in (select id from TableOne where id != 1)) s )) s )
delete from TableThree where tableTwo_id in (select id from (select * from TableTwo where tableOne_id in (select id from TableOne where id != 1)) s )
delete from TableTwo where tableOne_id in (select id from TableOne where id != 1)
delete from TableFive where tableOne_id in (select id from TableOne where id != 1)
delete from TableOne where id != 1
```

Которые удалят только то, что нам нужно.

Comment: Спасибо большое , помогли!
Извиняюсь, что сразу не уточнил вопрос.
Задача изменилась. Существует та же база данных, в которой неизвестное количество таблиц, они естественно связанны друг с другом. Требуется удалить записи только с первой таблицы(параметр который передаем в процесс).Записи с связанных таблиц удалять не нужно, нужно удалить только зависимости или сделать так что бы удалились все записи с нужной таблицы(параметр). Условия(неизвестность структуры базы) те же. Спасибо еще раз за ответ!

Comment: Так же протестировав ваш метод , получил ошибку : Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Procedure tr_tbl_Contact_ID, Line 169
The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "%CONSTRAINT_NAME%". The conflict occurred in database "%DB_NAME%", table "%dbo.tbl_Table%", column '%ColumnName%'.
The statement has been terminated.

Comment: @BorisDanylenko Я дополнил ответ. Надеюсь он поможет. Что касается ошибки - не зная на какой структуре данных она происходит - ничего не могу сказать по этому поводу, к сожалению.

Comment: @Aplnvent Спасибо за ответы. Такой вопрос, может ли предложенный вами запрос(первый) выполнятся с ошибкой, из-за того что на эту таблицу(название которой передается в параметре в процесс) завязано слишком много других таблиц(около 400-600)?

Comment: @Aplnvent первый запрос завершился успешно! Большое спасибо за помощь! Последний вопрос, не буду больше вас беспокоить!
Мне нужно удалять все записи с таблицы, кроме одной, куда прописать это условие?
Условие должно типа 'DELETE FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE Name!= 'VALUE''

Comment: @BorisDanylenko Под `TABLE_NAME` подразумевается таблица имя которой передается в параметре процедуры или это какая-то конкретная таблица? В качестве `VALUE` всегда какая-то константа или это значение тоже должно передаваться через параметр процедуры? Это условие должно быть только для одной таблицы или может быть ряд таблиц с таким или схожим ограничением?

Comment: @Aplnvent, TABLE_NAME = в вашей процедуре(первый предложенный вариант) входящий параметр(имя таблицы(table_name)).Это таблица, которую нужно изначально удалить.
VALUE = входящий параметр в процедуру(VARCHAR(MAX)).
Условие только для одной таблицы.
Спасибо за помощь!

Comment: @BorisDanylenko Дополнил ответ в конце, надеюсь это то, что Вам нужно.

Comment: @Aplnvent большое спасибо!

Comment: @Aplnvent доброго времени!
Появилась проблема в выполнением написанного вами запроса.
Если создавать таблицы вручную, то процедура всё удаляет, работает как надо, одним словом. Но когда процедуру создаю на рабочей базе, процедура выполняется, но ругается на первый ForeignKey, который отобразился бы в консоли если бы я писал инструкцию DELETE FROM.Полный текст ошибки стандартный : 
The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "FConstraintName". The conflict occurred in database "DatabaseName", table "dbo.tbl_TableName", column 'ColumnName'.

Comment: К сожалению, не видя схемы, удаленно сложно что-то сказать... Получается, что не сформировался запрос, который должен был удалить соответствующие данные. Тут я могу только гадать не имея возможность повторить проблему у себя ...