# Удалить несвязанные записи в таблице sql server (postgresql)

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-server, database-cursor

В базе данных имеется таблица MyTable. На записи этой таблицы имеются ссылки (FOREIGN - PRIMARY KEY) из других таблиц. В таблице MyTable есть поле MyValue. Требуется создать запрос, который удаляет в таблице MyTable записи, на которые нет ссылок ни из каких других таблиц и возвращает список удаленных MyValue.

Есть решение подобной задачи [Удаление значений из связанных таблиц](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/443493/) , но не понимаю как его модифицировать. Спасибо!

**UpDate1**
В идеале нужно решение для обоих СУБД: Sql Server и PostgreSql.

Comment: delete from mytable where id not in(select fkey from tab1 union select fkey from tab2 ....) returning MyValue

Comment: We know only about MyTable. No Names. no quantity etc.

Comment: Определитесь с СУБД и удалите лишний тег.

Comment: Вообще-то мне нужно решение для обоих СУБД. В таком случае я могу оставить как есть ? Или это рекомендация модератора, от которой нельзя отказаться ?

Comment: А ваша задача состоит из двух независимых задач (и соответственно на stackoverflow это должны быть разные вопросы). 1. прикинуть какой должен быть запрос,(это я написал в начале для postgre). 2. Получить имена всех таблиц/колонок имеющих связи с данной (легко гуглится например по фразе "_postgresql get foreign keys for table_"). Далее берете два эти пункта и на любом языке (можно и на языке процедур SQL нужной СУБД) пишите составитель динамического запроса 1 на основе списка 2.